# Ways to simplify arctan() in integral results?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Lately when I was computing $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}},$$I got the result$$-2\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}-1}{x}}-\ln\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}-1}{x}\right)+\mathbf{C}.$$However, Wolfram|Alpha gives me [its result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F(1%2BSqrt%5B1-2*x-x%5E2%5D),%20x%5D) in a different form, which may be written as$$\arcsin{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}-x+1}{\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}+x+3}}+\mathbf{C'},$$and I accordingly found that actually$$-2\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}-1}{x}}=\arcsin{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\pi}{4},$$a much neater expression! But apparently, without Wolfram|Alpha, I couldn't have found this neat relation that turns a complicated $2\arctan$ into a neat $\arcsin$ at all, so I've been wondering if there are any general way to **simplify these $\arctan$s in integral expressions**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such simplifications are possible thanks to the identities

$$\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x},\\\tan x=\sqrt{1+\sec^2x}$$ and many similar, also written

$$\arccos t=\arcsin\sqrt{1-t^2},\\\arccos t=\arctan\sqrt{1-\frac1{t^2}}$$

and so on.

But it doesn't seem possible to predict the simplifications that their use can yield without trying them.

It is likely that Alpha used a substitution with a sine rather than with a tangent, which gave a simpler expression "by chance" (though here the "simpler" character of the solution is questionable).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does seem that the form of the integral result largely depends on how we make a substitution, and to deduce a neater form requires such practice and experience.

Comment: @MinutesSneezer: in rigorous, formal terms, I would say that this is a matter of… luck !

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
1-2x-x^2=2-(1+2x+x^2)=2-(1+x)^2
$$
so you can do the substitution $u\sqrt{2}=1+x$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du
$$

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @clathratus It shows how WolframAlpha arrived at $\arcsin\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Apparently the substitution I use (*Euler substitution*, $\sqrt{1-2x-x^2}=xt+1$) in this case leads to a more complicated result than *trigonometric substitution*!